# Referencing a table with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, selection

I'll try to explain my situation as accurately as possible.

```
    1       2       3       4       5
1   3352    3635    4458    4137    4690

2   3352    3635    4458    4137    4690

3   3352    3635    4458    4137    4690

4   3352    3635    4458    4137    4690

5   3352    3635    4458    4137    4690
```

So the above table is purely to illustrate my problem. My actual table will contain changing values.

I've another function providing me with some values, for example: 2 and 5.

So basically I want to only search in the columns numbered 2 and 5. And I want to know the minimal value.

Now for the tricky part, next to the minimal cost I want it to return the corresponding row number (the 1-5 to the left) out which the value came. Now to top it all of. If there are two values that are the same, it should choose the one with the highest row number. So the minimal value will be the same but it will return the highest row number.

I've been trying this with regular excel functions for weeks and did not get what I wanted. The idea is to have a function that can be dragged down and calculated multiple times with differing inputs (different columns to reference). While all the functions I could find where to complicated to replicate.

I hope anybody has an idea. I'm currently looking at VBA but also there I've not yet been able to build something that works.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of the columns to check and then get the overall min of those columns:

```
Sub MinFromColumns()
   Dim ColumnsToCheck(1 To 3) As Long
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

   ColumnsToCheck(1) = 2
   ColumnsToCheck(2) = 5
   ColumnsToCheck(3) = 7

   overallmin = wf.Min(Columns(ColumnsToCheck(1)))
   For i = 2 To 3
      If wf.Min(Columns(ColumnsToCheck(i))) < overallmin Then overallmin = wf.Min(Columns(ColumnsToCheck(i)))
   Next i
   MsgBox overallmin
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is an example of getting the column selectors from worksheet cells:

```
Sub MinFromColumns()
   Dim ColumnsToCheck(1 To 3) As Long
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

   ColumnsToCheck(1) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K1")
   ColumnsToCheck(2) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("L1")
   ColumnsToCheck(3) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("M1")

   overallmin = wf.Min(Columns(ColumnsToCheck(1)))
   For i = 2 To 3
      If wf.Min(Columns(ColumnsToCheck(i))) < overallmin Then overallmin = wf.Min(Columns(ColumnsToCheck(i)))
   Next i
   MsgBox overallmin
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

Monday arrived sooner than expected.
Delete the old code and replace it with:

```
Sub MinFromColumns()
   Dim OverallMin As Variant
   Dim ColumnsToCheck(1 To 3) As Long
   Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, r As Range
   Dim addy As String, rColumn As Range
   Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

   ColumnsToCheck(1) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("K1")
   ColumnsToCheck(2) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("L1")
   ColumnsToCheck(3) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("M1")

   OverallMin = wf.Min(Columns(ColumnsToCheck(1)))

   For i = 2 To 3
      Set rColumn = Columns(ColumnsToCheck(i)).Cells
      If wf.Min(rColumn) < OverallMin Then
         OverallMin = wf.Min(rColumn)
         Set r = rColumn.Find(what:=OverallMin)
         addy = r.Address(0, 0)
      End If
   Next i

   MsgBox OverallMin & vbCrLf & addy
End Sub
```

*addy* gives the exact location of the minimum value,(both row and column)

Comment: Thank you very much for this speedy answer! What I would like to know is how I can link the ColumnsToCheck to certain cells in the spreadsheet.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! This was weeks of prodding to no avail with regular excel functions. I'd like to ask one more thing.

If I would like to complicate this a bit more by saying that I want to restrict the row inputs. Meaning that some selected cells are restricting the columns and some others are restricting the rows. For example if I were to choose row 2 and 3 (just need 2 input restrictions for the rows) then I would like it to return the row number with the corresponding minimum within the restricted columns (for each of the two rows). And the column number out of which that value came.

Comment: @Confusion752  That will require a bit more code................check back Monday.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help until now. I will check back monday.

Comment: Feels like Christmas has arrived early :). 

I've played around with it a bit but it still only returns the row number (the same thing your EDIT#1 did). Maybe I'm understanding the function wrong. Could you give me short explanation of the various elements?

I'll be selecting out of 8 columns, maximum 4 columns (cell values) to be checked at one time. While the input for the rows remain 2 cells. Referring back to my example: if row input is 2 & 4 and column input is 3,4 & 5. It should give me (4137, 4137, 2,4,4) --> (value,value,row1,row2,column)

Thanks again for all your effort!